# IntelliJ uses snapshots with timestamps instead of -SNAPSHOT to build artifact

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, build, nexus, snapshot

I have a project with snapshot dependencies. For simplification let's say that there is an project A which depends on library B-0.1-SNAPSHOT.

```
A depends on B
```

B resides within Nexus repository as a snapshot. I can see that it is stored with timestamp so the actual name in Nexus is something like: B-0.1-20141126.171716-67.jar

After executing:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

on project A, dependency B is downloaded from Nexus to my local repository. There I can find two jars of library B:

```
B-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
B-0.1-20141126.171716-67.jar
```

So far so good.

After maven build is complete I can see that B-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar was taken to build A artifact (.war file)

I also have project A imported to IntelliJ as a maven project. There I run it on Tomcat. Project is build by IntelliJ and B-0.1-20141126.171716-67.jar is added to .war file.

**At the end I have .war with both B-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and B-0.1-20141126.171716-67.jar within WEB-INF/lib directory.**

For me is seems like a bug in IntelliJ because B-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar should be taken from local maven repository... not the timespamped version. Is there any way to force IntelliJ to act propeply?

Maven version is 3.2.3, IntelliJ 14.0.1 (but the same behavior was on 13).

Answer (score 1):

I was faced to the same problem today, and I found how to disable this feature.

`F4` on your module, and go to `artifacts` then select the name of your artifact `webapp:exploded` and check the `show contents` radio at the bottom of the frame.

Go to `WEB-INF/lib` and search for your dependecy `B-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and expand the line you will see a `compile output` folder in it, just remove it, then repackage and run, you will now only have the `B-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and the one with the timestamp should be gone.

The downside of this is that you will have to make sure to `mvn install` your `B` module before running the `A` module within IntelliJ, because IntelliJ won't package your dependency and bundle it with the code you've just edited but not installed in your local maven repository.

Comment: Hi Alex, are using IntelliJ 14? I have a problem with step "expand the line you will see a compile output folder in it, just remove it". There is line "compile output' but I'not able to remove it.

Comment: I just had to right click and select "Remove", I'll make a screenshot at work later today.

Comment: My problem was slightly different.  I had artifacts that were built in other IntelliJ projects exhibiting this problem.  In the exploded view (mine was an EAR:App-Inf/lib) I removed them as archives and readded them as "Library Files" (Maven GAVs)

Comment: @Alex, can you attache more instruction? I can fix it if followin: *1.* open project structure *2.* in modules select webui *3.* in tab "dependencies" find my SNAPSHOT dependency and chane for it classes to "B-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" instead B-0.1-20141126.171716-67.jar (for example). Or it is error way and I must do change in artifacts only?